# Copying reports from new workspace to classic workspace

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to copy a report from a new workspace to classic workspace. However, i do not see an option to select the classic workspace when i click on copy button. Is there any way to copy the report from a new workspace experience to classic?

Your help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Classic workspaces are being deprecated in October. You will have to recreate/redeploy objects tothat workspace as you can't copy to classic

Answer (score 0):

Copying reports from workspace to workspace is only supported with the 'New' Workspace experience. Classic Workspaces will be removed at some point, it is highly recommended that you [upgrade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-upgrade-workspaces) them to the New Experience.